# Getting "undefined is not an object" when chaining .connect() methods in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api

I am trying to chain .connect methods to my AudioNode.
Just like in this example: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/webaudio-method-chaining/

It works in Chrome and Firefox but I get "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'source.connect(gainNode).connect')" in Safari. Is there any way to solve this?

```
const $audioPlayer = document.querySelector('.audio-player')
const audio = new AudioContext()
const gainNode = audio.createGain()
const source = audio.createMediaElementSource($audioPlayer)
source.connect(gainNode).connect(audio.destination)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari's implementation of the Web Audio API is not only prefixed but unfortunately also very outdated. The `connect()` method does always return `undefined` in Safari.

To make your example work in Safari you can rewrite line 2 and split line 5 into two calls.

```
const $audioPlayer = document.querySelector('.audio-player'); // unchanged

const audio = new webkitAudioContext();

const gainNode = audio.createGain(); // unchanged
const source = audio.createMediaElementSource($audioPlayer); // unchanged

source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audio.destination);
```

If you want to write your code as if it targets the newest iteration of the Web Audio API you can use a library.

I'm the author of [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context). There is also [web-audio-api-shim](https://github.com/mohayonao/web-audio-api-shim) which polyfills the `connect()` method as well.

To use the standardized-audio-context library you would just need to add an import statement to your code.

```
import { AudioContext } from 'standardized-audio-context';

// everything else can be left unchanged
const $audioPlayer = document.querySelector('.audio-player');
const audio = new AudioContext();
const gainNode = audio.createGain();
const source = audio.createMediaElementSource($audioPlayer);

source
    .connect(gainNode)
    .connect(audio.destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating

```
const audio = new AudioContext()
```

try to use this code:

```
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
```

This works in most browsers.

Comment: Actually I have it like this, and this does not help.

Comment: @ra_sv Did you check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode?